# Correct way to write X bytes to a file descriptor where X is a unsigned 64-bit integer

Tags: c

Consider the following C function:

```
static void                                                      
write_buf_to_disk(int fd, void *buf, __u64 size) {               
    const char* char_buf = buf;
    __u64 written = 0;                                           
    while (size > 0) {
        ssize_t res = write(fd, char_buf, size);
        if (res == -1) {                                         
            if (errno == EINTR) {                                
                // Write interrupted before anything written.    
                continue;                                        
            }                                                    
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "write");                          
        }                                                        
        written += res;
        char_buf += res;
        size -= res;
    }                                                                              
}
```

The function reads bytes out of `buf` until the requested number of bytes have been written. The type of `size` is out of my control, and must be a `__u64`.

I don't think this is portable due to friction between `ssize_t` and `__u64`.

`ssize_t` comes from a rather vague POSIX extension which AFAICS guarantees to be:

- at least 16-bits wide
- signed
- the same size as a `size_t`

So in theory `ssize_t` could be (unlikely, I know) 512 bits wide, meaning that `written += res` invokes undefined behaviour.

How does one guard against this in a portable fashion?

Comment: Why would it invoke UB?

Comment: You can change the loop so that it writes at most `SSIZE_MAX` in each iteration.

Comment: `char_buf += written; size -= written;` should be `char_buf += res; size -= res;`.

Comment: @Ian Abbott, That's my fault. Already fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res` will be no higher than `write`'s third argument, so all you have to do is constrain the 3rd argument of `write` to be no larger than the largest positive value that `res` (`ssize_t`) can store.

In other words, replace

```
ssize_t res = write(fd, char_buf, size);
```

with

```
size_t block_size = SSIZE_MAX;
if (block_size > size)
   block_size = size;

ssize_t res = write(fd, char_buf, block_size);
```

You get:

```
static void
write_buf_to_disk(int fd, void *buf, __u64 size) {
    const char* char_buf = buf;
    size_t block_size = SSIZE_MAX;
    while (size > 0) {
        if (block_size > size)
            block_size = size;

        ssize_t res = write(fd, char_buf, block_size);
        if (res == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;

            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "write");
        }

        char_buf += res;
        size     -= res;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean to use `block_size` in the third write arg, right?

Comment: Fixed. I appear to be more tired than I realized.

Comment: Thanks. I think I like this solution. Let me try to break it now :)

Comment: hmm now you're shadowing the `block_size` with your auto var declaration

Comment: So I *think* this works as long as the block size fits in a 16-bit unsigned, correct?

Comment: @Antti Haapala, Argh! Fixed. I'm going back to bed.

Comment: @Edd Barrett, Works for any value 64-bit unsigned size. (You could even switch `size` to a 128-bit type, and it would still work.)

Comment: Ah yes. I think I get it.

Comment: The key here is that `size_t block_size = SSIZE_MAX;` must always succeed, then `block_size > size` is valid since this compares types of the same signedness.

Comment: Eh? They are both unsigned.

Comment: And I suppose the `char *` is needed because pointer arithmetic is invalid on `void *`.

Comment: I'm going to wait a while to see if a better solution shows up, but this one is the best candidate so far IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

In

```
ssize_t res = write(fd, buf, size);
```

even if `ssize_t` would be 512 bits wide, as you suggested, the compiler promotes the result of `write` (64 bits) to that size. So the comparison would still work.

In

```
written += res;
```

the compiler would give you a warning, but 64 bits to count the number of bytes written is really gigantic (~10<sup>19</sup> bytes max). So you're unlikely to miss any write even though the addition is from a 512 bits to a 64 bits.

You could also assign the size to a `ssize_t` at the beginning of the function

```
write_buf_to_disk(int fd, void *buf, __u64 size64) { 
   ssize_t size = size64;
```

that would make the rest of the body in line with the system functions.

Comment: I'd rather find a solution with no warnings.

Comment: @EddBarrett Practically 10^19 is impossible to reach. Just cast at the beginning of the function `ssize_t size = (ssize_t)size64;` and there won't be any (relevant) warning.

Answer (score 1):

The C11 standard says (7.19):

> The types used for `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` should not have an integer conversion rank
>   greater than that of `signed long int` unless the implementation supports objects
>   large enough to make this necessary.

So `size_t` and `ssize_t` are unlikely to be 512 bits, unless you run on a 512-bit processor.

Right now you are extremely likely **not** to need more than 64 bits for any memory or disk size. That limits the amount of data you can have in a `write` statement.